# unable to access public enum from within a framework

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

I have been working on developing a framework and I have decided to create custom enums that extend the Error protocol to report to the host application when a domain specific error is encountered.

i.e.

```
public enum MyCustomError: Error {
    case customCase(message: String)
}
```

from the host application I have a response call back that is another enum with associated value

i.e.

```
public enum MyCustomResponse {
    case success
    case error(Error)
}
```

form within the host application I try to access the error by doing the following

i.e.

```
let responseHandler: (MyCustomResponse) -> Void = { response in

    switch response {
        case .error(let error):
            if case let MyCustomModule.MyCustomError.customCase(theErrorMessage) = error {
                print(theErrorMessage)
            }
    }
}
```

what I am getting is a message from the compiler telling me that `MyCustomModule has no member named MyCustomError`. If a loose the `MyCustomModule.` then the compiler complains `Use of unresolved identifier 'MyCustomError'`. I am importing `MyCustomModule`, and the access level of the `MyCustomError` is `public`, any ideas on how to solve this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Note: I am developing my framework via cocoapods version `1.1.1` and using Xcode 8.2.1, swift version 3.0.2, supporting iOS version 8.0 and above.

*Generated interface*

```
import Foundation 

public enum MyCustomError : Error { 
    case customCase(message: String) 
}
```

Comment: Can you show what object contains the `public enum MyCustomError: Error` declaration?

Comment: `MyCustomError` is specified above, and I call it `MyCustomError.customCase("MyCustomObject property A can not be blank")` for example. @AshleyMills

Comment: What I mean is, is the declaration contained in another object, or is it at the top level?

Comment: @AshleyMills top level, it lives within its own file

Comment: I can't reproduce this, something must be wrong with your module map or settings.

Comment: @JAL any pointers within settings that might be producing this ?

Comment: Can you post the **Generated interface** for the file that contains the enum? (Click the 4 squares button top left of the code editor, and click *Generated interface*)

Comment: If you command+click on `MyCustomModule` do you see the declaration for  `MyCustomError`?

Comment: @JAL yes I can CMD+Click into the declaration, it takes me to the correct file

Comment: @AshleyMills
`
import Foundation

public enum MyCustomError : Error {

    case customCase(message: String)
}
`

Comment: In the application using the framework do you have `import MyCustomModule`?

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a unit test of that framework?

Comment: @faircloud yes I am importing MyCustomModule

Comment: it seems like people might right, it is a problem with some kind of setting, tested it out on separate project https://github.com/anuragajwani/framework_pod_enums_test

Comment: Your project is building fine here. Is this what you are saying? If so, can you post a link to a sample showing the issue?

Comment: @shallowThought I was able to proceed working but I could not find the cause, check my answer below. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while trying out every little thing I could think of, even *sandboxing* the problem in a new repo (check github.com/anuragajwani/framework_pod_enums_test) without the ability to reproduce it I ended re-cloning the repository with the issue in question and reapplied all the changes and it worked no problem. Pitty I could not find the underlying problem, but by comparing each configuration setting in comparison with the sandboxed project and everything matching exactly I gave up. I have hunch that it had to with the compiler which given how flaky it is it would be no surprise.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue. In my case I just set the `"Build Active Architecture Only" to "No"` in the `Build Settings` and the issue was gone.